# Change width Angular powered Bootstrap tooltip

Tags: angular, tooltip, bootstrapper

I would like to change the width of my tooltip, but can't figure out how to write the CSS code for that. The HTML code is the following:

```
                    <th class="number">
                        <span class="header-content" jhiSortBy="sumPerAmount">
                            <span class="header-text" jhiTranslate="something.sumPerAmount" ngbTooltip="VERY_LONG_TOOLTIP_TEXT_VERY_LONG_TOOLTIP_TEXT_VERY_LONG_TOOLTIP_TEXT" tooltipClass="wide-tooltip">Sum per
                                amount</span>
                            <fa-icon class="sort-icon" [icon]="'sort'"></fa-icon>
                        </span>
                     </th>
```

CSS-code:

```
.wide-tooltip .tooltip-inner{
background-color: darkgreen;
width: 300px;
```

}

Comment: it looks ok, you also need to override max-width in your CSS to max-width: 300px;

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the tooltip CSS styling 'encapsulation' property must also be specified in component annotation.

```ts
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'tooltip-custom-class-example',
  templateUrl: 'tooltip-custom-class-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['tooltip-custom-class-example.css'],
  // Need to remove view encapsulation so that the custom tooltip style defined in
  // `tooltip-custom-class-example.css` will not be scoped to this component's view.
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read documentation of customClass of tooltip.

here is [link](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tooltip/examples#customclass) of documentation and here is [link](https://stackblitz.com/angular/bbeyoxyyvjv?file=app%2Ftooltip-customclass.html) of stackblitz example

Comment: I have tried your suggested solution but it still doesn't work. I have edited my question so you can see what I have done.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jvuq7g?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

here is a link of working example. and what i see is, in official website in demo example they are using `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,` in component ts file. after adding this line, custom class was working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

**Bootstrap Tooltips**

If you need to have different custom tooltips so do something like this:

Suppose you want to have two different tooltip styles and keep the main bootstrap tooltip:

1-Add custom styles to the main styles.css file for each of them:

```
::ng-deep .primary-tooltip .tooltip-inner {
    background-color: yellow;
    color: black;
}
::ng-deep .secondary-tooltip .tooltip-inner {
    background-color: red;
    color: black;
}
```

2-Implement the HTML as shown below:

```
<div title="bootstrap tooltip" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top"></div>
<div title="primary" data-bs-custom-class="primary-tooltip" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top"></div>
<div title="secondary" data-bs-custom-class="secondary-tooltip" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top"></div>
```