# Change tool-tip background color in Angular

Tags: css, angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a tooltip, and I want to change his background. The default background is black.

```
 <ng-template #start>Start</ng-template>
 <button [ngbTooltip]="start"  type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger">
     <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i>
 </button>
```

Could you, please, help me with this?

Comment: Use `[ngStyle]={background-color: red}`?

Comment: what is this `ngbTooltip` ?? is that any npm package ??

Comment: did you try .tooltip-inner class to change the background color? Are you using ng-bootstrap?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Width and background color of ng bootstrap tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44681992/width-and-background-color-of-ng-bootstrap-tooltip)

Comment: @AkhilAravind  ngbTooltip  is from tooltip package

Comment: @NicholasK I tried with with ngStyle but it doesn't work

Comment: How did you use `ngStyle`? Can you paste that attempt here?

Comment: [custom bootstrap tooltip in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53592603/change-width-angular-powered-bootstrap-tooltip/70501545#70501545)

Answer (score 1):

There need to be couple of css changes,

Check stackblitz demo [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nfmmme)

You need to add below css to the root style file. Replace red with your desired color.

```
/* Add application styles & imports to this file! */

.tooltip-inner{
  background-color: red!important;
}
.bs-tooltip-auto[x-placement^=right] .arrow::before, .bs-tooltip-right .arrow::before{
  border-right-color:red!important;
}

.bs-tooltip-auto[x-placement^=left] .arrow::before, .bs-tooltip-left .arrow::before{
  border-left-color:red!important;
}

.bs-tooltip-auto[x-placement^=top] .arrow::before, .bs-tooltip-top .arrow::before{
  border-top-color:red!important;
}

.bs-tooltip-auto[x-placement^=bottom] .arrow::before, .bs-tooltip-bottom .arrow::before{
  border-bottom-color:red!important;
}
```

Comment: [custom bootstrap tooltip in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53592603/change-width-angular-powered-bootstrap-tooltip/70501545#70501545)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a class (e.x tool-info-class) and add on your tooltip

```
.tool-info-class .tooltip-inner {
  background-color: #fff;
}

tooltipClass="tool-info-class"
```

An example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yo7esv

Comment: Do I need to put the tooltipClass in the button ? because I tried and it does't work..

Comment: <button [ngbTooltip]="start" tooltipClass="tool-info-class"  type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger"> or try with brackets
<button [ngbTooltip]="start" [tooltipClass]="tool-info-class"  type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger">

Comment: I am using it on img tag and it's working <img src="assets/images/info-button.svg" class="ml-1" tooltipClass="tool-info-class" alt="info-business-name" placement="right" ngbTooltip="Your text here" style="margin: 0!important;" >

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML, add `tool-tip-btn` to your `button`’s `class` attribute, making it like this:

```html
class="btn btn-outline-danger tool-tip-btn"
```

Then in your CSS, refer to that class:

```css
.tool-tip-btn {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: I dont think it will apply bg on tooltip. this will apply bg on btn with class tooltip

Answer (score 0):

Its define in their OFFICIAL DOC [Here](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tooltip/examples#triggers)

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" ngbTooltip="Nice class!"
  tooltipClass="my-custom-class">
  Tooltip with custom class
</button>
```

and in you TS

```
styles: [`
    .my-custom-class .tooltip-inner {
      background-color: darkgreen;
      font-size: 125%;
    }
    .my-custom-class .arrow::before {
      border-top-color: darkgreen;
    }
  `]
```

and the [link](https://stackblitz.com/run?file=app%2Ftooltip-customclass.ts) for more info

Answer (score 0):

Below has worked for me earlier

```
::ng-deep .tooltip-inner {
    background-color:#707070!important
}
```